# How and why is the List.removeRange() method affecting other variables?

Tags: dart

I don't understand how `data.removeRange()` can effect my copy of the data.

```
void main() {
  int lengthdata = 50;
  List<double> data = List.filled(lengthdata,0.0,growable: true);
  List<double> copydata;
  for (int i = 0; i < 10;i++) {
    data.add(0.0);
  }
  copydata = data;
  print(copydata.length);
  print(data.length);
  data.removeRange(0, data.length - lengthdata);
  print(copydata.length);
  print(data.length);
}
```

Output:

```
60
60
50
50
```

Comment: `copydata = data` does not make a copy of your list but instead copies the reference to your list. So now, both `copydata` and `data` points to the same `List` instance. In your case, you can call: `copydata = data.toList()` to copy your list.

Comment: I should note that you are creating a copy of the list but not a deep copy of each object in the list. In your case, this is fine since you have `double` objects in your list which are immutable.

Comment: You can upvote if the answer is helped :)  https://stackoverflow.com/a/64425801/10659482

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use it like this:

```
   copydata = List.from(data);
```

You can read more from [here](https://flutter-examples.com/flutter-dart-copy-clone-list-into-another-list/).